# Abrir archivo seleccionado por su ruta - [VB6]

Tags: vb6, csv

Hola tengo una duda espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un `archivo .csv` que quiero abrir pero se debe seleccionar el archivo previamente, una vez seleccionado obtengo su ruta y su nombre, pero aquí viene el problema, como lo hago para pasar su ruta y nombre a la cadena de conexión para que puedas ser cargado.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function LeerTxt(Directorio As String) As ADODB.Recordset
  On Error GoTo ErrorFunction
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
  Dim ruta
  Dim directorios

  ruta = Form1.File1.FileName
  directorios = Form1.File1.Path & "\"
  MsgBox ruta 'PARA COMPROBAR QUE SE ENCUENTREN LLENAS
  MsgBox directorios 'PARA COMPROBAR QUE SE ENCUENTREN LLENAS

  cn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & "DBQ=" & directorios & ";", "", ""

  rs.Open "select * from [ruta]", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
  Set LeerTxt = rs

  Set rs = Nothing
  Set cn = Nothing

  Exit Function
ErrorFunction:
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
  Err.Clear
```

End Function

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, faltaba concatenar. Saludos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar de "ruta", puede ser "archivo" o "tabla" el nombre de la variable, y también acuérdate de definir el tipo, en este caso es de tipo `String`